# Combining 2 png in one with convert

Tags: macos, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using convert from ImageMagick to combine 2 png in one using this script :

```
convert background.png logo.png -layers merge final_background.png
```

It is working but I would like to move the logo at 20 pixels from the top, is it possible ?

Thanks a lot

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this :

```
convert background.png -page +0+130 stationLogo.png -page +0+440 -layers merge Default.png
```